# play audio file in chat with seekbar in android

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android and I want to play audio in a list-view. My xml file is like this. How can play audio and update seek bar?
While I am playing the audio file in list then only the last seek bar is moving.
Similar like whatsapp chat app.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_chat_item_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main_chat_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_green"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_image_part"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_message_image"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/temp_picture" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_message_chat_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="sample text message"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <!-- For Adio -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_audio_part"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/playbutton_bg"
                    android:onClick="playAudio" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
                    android:focusable="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_message_devider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_send_time_chat_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_user_sender_name_chat_item"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_mesage_send_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_edit"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main_chat_item_f"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_display_name"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_image_part_f"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pb_loading_f"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_message_image_f"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/temp_picture" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_message_chat_item_f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="hi" />

            <!-- For Adio -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_audio_part_f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/play_f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/playbutton_bg"
                    android:onClick="playFAudio" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar1_f"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_f"
                    android:focusable="false" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_f"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_message_devider_f"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_send_time_chat_item_f"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="SDFDSFDSFSDD" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_mesage_send_status_f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_edit"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such listeners so that you can keep calling them but how ever you can go with a timer and keep increment the values and change the seekbar values.